# ASP.NET MVC - updating an existing model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am creating a web application that contains a model for the user. After creating the model without errors, I'm trying to update the password for the user (Change password form). Every time I try to update the model, the db.savechanges() throw an exception (Title and the category are required although this user has entries for both fields). When I try to debug this controller method, no exceptions are thrown and The user contains data for both the category and the faculty title!!

here is my user model:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Required]
    public virtual FacultyTitle Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be less than {1} characters and more than {2} characters.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Position")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Required]
    public virtual Categories Categorie { get; set; }
```

And here is the part of the method that I am using to update the user password:

```
   user.Password = Helper.EncryptPassword(newPass);
   db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
```

The exception message: The title and the categories field are required

Please any one help me

Comment: Can you post your edit form as well? Chances are that `FacultyTitle` and `Categories` aren't being repopulated on the submission because they either aren't being output correctly for edit, or you don't have an empty construct for them so the model can't be re-established. A look at how you're outputting the edit model would be most helpful. -- Follow-Up: Are you checking that `ModelState.IsValid` is true before proceeding with changes by the way?

Comment: @BradChristie There is no edit form. That's a part of the controller action method having two parameters `Email` and `ActivationCode`.
`public ActionResult ResetPassword(String Email, String Token)
 {
var user db.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == mail);
user.password="Anything"
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; `
db.SaveChanges();}'

I am not checking for `ModelState.IsValid` as well

Comment: What submits to the controller then? Two input boxes not bound to the original model?

Comment: It's just a link the user receives in order to reset his password:
http://localhost:60242/Account/ResetPassword?Email=amreha2002%40gmail.com&Token=oKMRqJmi1RNFp2o4qjF3GRk1GxG%2B2krkEiNOR59x5ozOImk2XqhVErRp8VhCFiW2

Comment: You can’t pass in an empty user model (except for password) and expect it to figure out which fields you want updated.

Comment: I am not passing an empty model. I am passing an email as a string then I am getting from the users table the entry that matches with that mail. Then I am only updating this user's password. Also, how come the exception happens only when I run the application normally. If I insert a break point inside this method body to see what's happening, everything just goes fine without any exception !

Comment: After you've done the `var user db.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == mail);` - have you debugged your code to see if all your properties are getting mapped during the select?